# Recycler View Unable to load data in the layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I try to run the app my recycler view unable to generate the output.
It is unable to load data and there is no error the code.

Below is adapter class
PlayerListAdapter.java

```
public class PlayerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerListAdapter.FeaturedViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<plaerListHelperClass> featuredLocation;

    public PlayerListAdapter(ArrayList<plaerListHelperClass> featuredLocation) {
        this.featuredLocation = featuredLocation;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FeaturedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.playerlist,parent,false);
        FeaturedViewHolder featuredViewHolder= new FeaturedViewHolder(view);
        return featuredViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeaturedViewHolder holder, int position) {

        plaerListHelperClass plaerListHelperClass = featuredLocation.get(position);
        String namep= plaerListHelperClass.getPlayerName();
        String mailp= plaerListHelperClass.getPlayerEmail();

        holder.name.setText(namep);
        holder.mail.setText(mailp);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return featuredLocation.size();
    }

    public static class FeaturedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView name,mail;

        public FeaturedViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerName);
            mail=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pmail);
        }
    }
```

mainactivity.java
This is main activity of my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView featuredRecycler;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        featuredRecycler=findViewById(R.id.playerListRecyclerView);

        featuredRecycler();
    }

    private void featuredRecycler() {
        featuredRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        ArrayList<plaerListHelperClass> featuredLocation = new ArrayList<>();

        featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));
        featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));
        featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));
        featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));

        adapter=new PlayerListAdapter(featuredLocation);

        featuredRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Build this helper class to contains the element that is to be send to the recycler view layout

plaerListHelperClass.java

```
public class plaerListHelperClass {
    String playerName;
    String playerEmail;

    public plaerListHelperClass(String playerName, String playerEmail) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.playerEmail = playerEmail;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public String getPlayerEmail() {
        return playerEmail;
    }
}
```

playerlist.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#897668"
        android:layout_weight="1.50"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pmail"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#897668"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/playerListRecyclerView"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to change layout_height of your recyclerview to match_parent and add these to your recyclerView in xml:         app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: It worked Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow,

your implementation is correct but I guess you forgot to add the Layout Manager for RecyclerView.

so you can do this by adding it in xml or in your java class as :

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

<!--    for Linear layout...-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/playerListRecyclerView"
        tools:listitem="@layout/playerlist"
        tools:itemCount="7"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or,

you can add it in your java class as

```
 private void featuredRecycler() {
            featuredRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    
            ArrayList<plaerListHelperClass> featuredLocation = new ArrayList<>();
    
            featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));
            featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));
            featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));
            featuredLocation.add(new plaerListHelperClass("Shubham","Shubham@gmail.com"));
    
            adapter=new PlayerListAdapter(featuredLocation);
    
            featuredRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
            featuredRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity))

        }
```

for more reference you can refer [https://www.javatpoint.com/android-recyclerview-list-example](http://JavaTPoint)